# Persistent BottomSheet peekHeight and STATE_COLLAPSED not drawing properly on Activity start

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, bottom-sheet

I have a CoordinatorLayout with a custom view and a persistent bottom sheet. I have disabled hiding for the bottom sheet and want to show the top couple of views in a LinearLayout in the collapsed state. To account for different screen sizes, I dynamically set the peekHeight in my activity's onCreate, after everything has been laid out.

The issue is when the activity first starts, the BottomSheet peeks at one height, and then after it is expanded and collapsed again the peekHeight seems to have changed. Interestingly enough, it visually looks like the peekHeight added is the layouts activity padding (16dp). However, the BottomSheetBehavior reports the same peekHeight for both.

I have created a hacky workaround for this, but I want to see if there is anything I am doing wrong. Below is a gif showing when I do not have my workaround and one when I am using my workaround. I have also included the relevant code and layout files. Again, It seems to be directly related to my padding (16dp), but I don't understand how to fix it.

**NOT using workaround:**

[image]

**Using workaround:**

[image]

**Activity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_schedule_details_activity);

    final CoordinatorLayout activityLayout =
            (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.edit_schedule_details_layout);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    // ... removed unrelated logic

    final View bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.edit_details_sheet);

    final LinearLayout peekContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.info_title_container);
    activityLayout
            .getViewTreeObserver()
            .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // Set the measured peek height and add in 16 dps to account for inconsistency
            // Adding the 16 dps is part of the workaround
            bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(peekContainer.getHeight());
                    //+ (int) (16 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density)); /* workaround */
            Timber.i("Title height: " + bottomSheetBehavior.getPeekHeight());
            bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
        }
    });

    bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);

            bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            String stateString = "";
            if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
                stateString = "Expanded";

                /* workaround */
                /*if(!bottomSheetSet){

                    // remove the extra 16 dp added since the layout now looks correct
                    bottomSheetBehavior
                            .setPeekHeight(
                                    bottomSheetBehavior.getPeekHeight()
                                            - (int) (16 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
                    bottomSheetSet = true;
                }*/
            }
            else if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) {
                stateString = "Collapsed";
                Timber.i("peekHeight = " + bottomSheetBehavior.getPeekHeight());
            }
            else if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
                stateString = "Hidden";
            }
            else if(newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING) {
                stateString = "Settling";
            }
            else if(newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING){
                stateString = "Dragging";
            }
            Timber.i("bottomSheetState = " + stateString);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

        }

    }); 

}
```

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/edit_schedule_details_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:background="#ff171e26">


    <com.cel.cortetcommercial.widget.ring_view.RingView
        android:id="@+id/edit_ringview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dip"
        app:inner_radius="95dip"
        app:outer_radius="130dip"
        app:color="@color/colorSecondaryDark"
        app:is_touchable="true"
        app:text_size="12dip"
        app:tick_length="0dip"
        app:tick_width="0dip"
        android:transitionName="@string/transition_details_to_edit"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/add_remove_button_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/edit_ringview"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/remove_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-"
            android:layout_gravity="end"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/edit_details_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
        app:behavior_hideable="false">

        <include layout="@layout/current_info_sheet">
        </include>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**current_info_sheet:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/info_container"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/info_title_container">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/segment_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:text="@string/placeholder"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Headline"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time_remaining"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:text="@string/placeholder"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/luminosity"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/color_warmth"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you figure this out? I see the same issue.

Comment: android:clipToPadding="true" -> might be related